Rider - Blazor WebAssembly standalone app: Error running
Im run into a weird issue. Its kinda hard to explain but whenever i create a blazor webassembly standalone app and try and run it. I always get the error: Error running 'BlazorApp2: IIS Express' and i get this error even with https and http and it only happen on this template. If i create a web api app it runs fine.
This is the launch settings but its just the default one
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40601",
      "sslPort": 44367
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7057;http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

I know its not much but has anyone else run into this error?
PS- if i CD into the directory and run dotnet run or dotnet watch the project builds and runs correctly so i think its something to do with rider

I'm not familiar with this particular issue. However, I also had hard days with Rider and IIS Express. Therefore, I completely scrubbed IIS Express and have only used Kestrel since then.
